# How retrieve all the database names in one Selectbox using ADO.net?

Tags: c#, ado.net

In database contains 50 databases (adventureworks,adventureworksDw,sampleDb.....)

How we can I retrieve all the databases names in one select box using ADO.net?

Can you please help me? Is there any solution?

Thanks,

Rajasekhar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this old procedure, worked fine for me

```
public void PopulateDatabaseNames(string connectionString, ComboBox cboDBNames)
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = null;
    SqlCommand cmd = null;
    SqlConnection cnn = null;
    try
    {
        using(cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using(cmd = new SqlCommand())
        using(da = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cnn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT NAME FROM master..sysdatabases order by NAME";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = cnn;
            SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                string name = myReader.GetString(0).ToLower();
                if (name != "master" && name != "tempdb" && name != "model" && name != "msdb")
                {
                    cboDBNames.Items.Add(name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "PopulateDatabasesNames");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your data access layer you should query the server with

```
Select name from sys.databases
```

You can the put the returned object as the datasource for you dropdownlist, and remember to call databind for the ddl!